# angularjs ui-select-choices dropdown aphabetical order depending on the input given

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

I'm using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select for the website I'm working on. Currently the code is as follows:

```
       <ui-select ng-model="model.states">
         <ui-select-match placeholder="State">
           {{$item.Name}}
         </ui-select-match>
         <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Code as item in statesArray | filter:$select.search">
            {{item.Name}}
         </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
```

When I type anything in the input field, for example "a", ui-select-choices shows all the fields containing "a" (by default). What I want to do is, I want to show all the states starting with "a" only. If nothing is typed in the input box, then show all the fields in alphabetical order. Can someone please propose a solution? I saw few other posts but no one has answered this question yet. Thanks in advance.

## Example

Here's an example, suppose states array has states like California, Connecticut, Alaska, Arizona, New York.

If nothing is typed in the input field, dropdown should show Alaska, Arizona, California, Connecticut, New York (which can be achieved using orderBy filter).

If user types "a" in the input field, dropdown should show Alaska, Arizona and no other fields as Alaska and Arizona are only fields starting with "a".
If user types "c", dropdown should show California, Connecticut.
If user types "ca", dropdown should show California only as it only matches the input string given.

Comment: Use Tony's solution with a custom filter https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/blob/master/src/filters/startsWith/startsWith.js

Comment: Thanks @KreepN. I was able to make it work using startsWith filter. I had one question. Do you know how can I pass text typed in the input field to the filter. I can use jquery selector like $('input.ui-select-search').val() but the problem with it is, I'm using multiple ui-select containers, it works for the first container but doesn't work for other containers. I'd like to pass the value typed in the ui-select container to the startsWith filter. Do you know how can I pass? $select.search won't work.

Answer (score 11):

If I understand you correctly, I think all you need to do is add

> | orderBy:'Name'

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item.Code as item in statesArray | filter:$select.search | orderBy:'Name'">
{{item.Name}}
</ui-select-choices>
```

Check out [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for more information

Comment: Yeah, this works for sorting the list alphabetically but it doesn't resolve the issue when user types anything in the input field. I edited the post, so that you can understand it better.

Answer (score 4):

After digging a little and with Tomy's and KreepN's help, I found the answer. Here it is,

```
   <ui-select ng-model="model.states">
     <ui-select-match placeholder="State">
       {{$item.Name}}
     </ui-select-match>
     <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Code as item in statesArray | startsWith:$select.search | orderBy:'Code'">
        {{item.Name}}
     </ui-select-choices>
   </ui-select>
```

startsWith Filter is as follows:

```
.filter('startsWith', function() {
    return function(array,search) {
        if(!_.isUndefined(array) && !_.isUndefined(search)) {
            var matches = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i].Name.toUpperCase().indexOf(search.toUpperCase()) === 0 &&
                    search.length <= array[i].Name.length) {
                    matches.push(array[i]);
                }
            }
            return matches;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the options above but I achieved the result only in this case.
It works for me:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="group in groups | filter: $select.search | orderBy:['name']">
  {{ group.name }}
</ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks